# How do I disable the chrome pop-up notifications using selenium in python?

Tags: python, selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

username = 'loremipsum'
password = 'loremipsum'

url = 'https://www.facebook.com/'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\kevin\Downloads\chromedriver")
driver.get(url)


driver.find_element_by_id('email').send_keys(username)
driver.find_element_by_id('pass').send_keys(password)

time.sleep(2)

driver.find_element_by_id('loginbutton').click()

time.sleep(10)
```

What do I have to do to disable a chrome notification I get "Facebook wants to show notifications, allow or block" when I sign in?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an option to your chrome driver before starting it.

```
options= webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--disable-notifications')
#options.add_argument("disable-notifications");
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\kevin\Downloads\chromedriver", chrome_options=options)
```